# Number not Printing in python when returning amount

Tags: python

I have some code which reads from a text file and is meant to print max and min altitudes but the min altitude is not printing and there is no errors.

```
altitude = open("Altitude.txt","r")

read = altitude.readlines()

count = 0

for line in read:
    count += 1

count = count - 1
print("Number of Different Altitudes: ",count)


def maxAlt(read):
    maxA = (max(read))
    return maxA

def minAlt(read):
    minA = (min(read))
    return minA

print()
print("Max Altitude:",maxAlt(read))
print("Min Altitude:",minAlt(read))
altitude.close()
```

I will include the Altitude text file if it is needed and once again the minimum altitude is not printing

Comment: `count = len(read)`

Comment: @OlvinRoght, `len(read) - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming, your file probably contains numbers & line-breaks (`\n`)

You are reading it here:

```
read = altitude.readlines()
```

At this point `read` is a list of strings.

Now, when you do:

```
minA = (min(read))
```

It's trying to get "the smallest string in `read`"

The smallest string is usually the empty string `""` - which most probably exists at the end of your file.

So your `minAlt` is actually getting printed. But it happens to be the empty string.

You can fix it by parsing the lines you read into numbers.

```
read = [float(a) for a in altitude.readlines() if a]
```

Comment: But if tumbelweed's file contain empty lines, would not that cause `[float(a) for a in altitude.readlines()]` to do `float("")` which result in error?

Comment: Right. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @rdas thanks this works i also have another question how would i go about adding every line from the text file containing a number and then dividing it amount the num of lines calculating the average and then displaying the average altititude?

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution

```
altitudeFile = open("Altitude.txt","r")

Altitudes = [float(line) for line in altitudeFile if line] #get file data into list.

Max_Altitude = max(Altitudes)
Min_Altitude = min(Altitudes)

altitudeFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this

```
with open('numbers.txt') as nums:
        lines = nums.read().splitlines()

results = list(map(int, lines))
print(results)
print(max(results))
```

the first two lines read file and store it as a list. third line convert string list to integer and the last one search in list and return max, use min for minimum.